# Adding English analyzer to a type in elastic search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I want to add English analyzer to a type in my ElasticSearch analyzer.
Something like:

```
    [ElasticsearchType(Name = "blogpost", IdProperty = "Id")]
public class BlogPost
{
    [String]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [String]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [String(Analyzer = LanguageAnalyzers.English, TermVector = TermVectorOption.WithOffsets)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

I am using C# NEST 2.x api
The erroneous part here is : 'LanguageAnalyzers.English' which I made up.

Any suggestions on how to do it correct?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? How do you create index?

Comment: I just get 'LanguageAnalyzers' does not exist in this context. also tried:   [String(Analyzer = "english", TermVector = TermVectorOption.WithOffsets)]

Comment: How do you create index?

Comment: internal void Index(BlogPost blogPost, string indexName, string typeName)
        {

            var res = 
           client.Index(blogPost, p => p
               .Index(indexName)
               .Type(typeName)
               .Id(blogPost.Id.ToString()));


        }

Answer (score 1):

The English Language Analyzer can be referred to with the [`"english"` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer)

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "blogpost", IdProperty = "Id")]
public class BlogPost
{
    [String]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [String]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [String(Analyzer = "english", TermVector = TermVectorOption.WithOffsets)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

client.CreateIndex("blogposts", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<BlogPost>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
        )
    )
);
```

yields

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "blogpost": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "body": {
          "type": "string",
          "term_vector": "with_offsets",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @belostoky No worries, happy to help :) If it answers your question, please feel free to mark the answer as accepted